# Argo stop workflow early, mark complete

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

Imagine I have a workflow with 5 steps.

Step 2 may or may not create a file as its output (which is then used as input to subsequent steps).

- If the file is created, I want to run the subsequent steps.
- If no file gets created in step 2, I want to mark the workflow as completed and not execute steps 3 through to 5.

I'm sure there must be a simple way to do this yet I'm failing to figure out how.

I tried by making step 2 return non-zero exit code when no file is created and then using
`when: "{{steps.step2.outputs.exitCode}} == 0"` on step 3, but that still executes step 4 and 5 (not to mention marks step 2 as "failed")

So I'm out of ideas, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a step that exits with a non-zero exit code fails the workflow.

I would suggest writing an [output parameter](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/examples/output-parameter.yaml) to determine whether the workflow should continue.

```yaml
- name: yourstep
  container:
    command: [sh, -c]
    args: ["yourcommand; if [ -f /tmp/yourfile ]; then echo continue > /tmp/continue; fi"]
  outputs:
    parameters:
    - name: continue
      valueFrom:
        default: "stop"
        path: /tmp/continue
```

Alternatively, you can [override the fail-on-nonzero-exitcode behavior](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/examples/exit-code-output-variable.yaml#L12) with `continueOn`.

```yaml
continueOn:
  failed: true
```

I'd caution against `continueOn.failed: true`. If your command throws a non-zero exit code for an unexpected reason, the workflow won't fail like it should, and the bug might go un-noticed.

Comment: coming across this now. Do you have a reference for a conditional on the workflow level? If continue == 'stop', end workflow? I have a similar problem to the above, so I created an output variable like you have listed here but it just progresses to the following step. Assuming I would then have to condition each subsequent step?